# jquery instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, api, instagram

using the following code---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/131324529876654234_1491525?client_id=afd15cca7d664a1c964d54bac0488b93",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            $("#pics").append("<img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img>");
        }
    }
});
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pics"></div>
</body>
```

I want to get an image to show up based on the id I pass in the api. For some reason it doesn't work. any one can tell me what im doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.data.images.thumbnail.url
```

There doesn't seem to be an array anywhere in the JSON that you're accessing.

Here is a dumbed-down version of your JSON to illustrate the point:

```
{
    ...
    "data": {
        ...
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com\/e41665005cf611e19896123138142014_6.jpg",
                "width":306,
                "height":306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com\/e41665005cf611e19896123138142014_5.jpg",
                "width":150,
                "height":150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com\/e41665005cf611e19896123138142014_7.jpg",
                "width":612,
                "height":612
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Reu2/

Comment: Thanks, that worked... can you please tell me how you were able to get the dumbed-down version of the JSON? is there a tool for this?

Comment: Well, I read a lot of JSON. So I just copied it, the removed everything I didn't want by hand. You can use a "prettifier" to make it more readable though: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

The url you are using is to bring back a specific media element (*a single photo*).

So you need to access it with `data.data.images.thumbnail.url`

You can use
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=afd15cca7d664a1c964d54bac0488b93`
to retrieve the popular media of that user and then the `data.data` is indeed an array.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://instagr.am/developer/endpoints/media/)

Answer (score 0):

data is not an array 
no need to reference data[i] just data 
http://jsbin.com/oxetok/edit#javascript,html,live